# How do display a $compile hyperlink

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $compile to compile a dynamically created hyperlink - so my hyperlink/click() event gets fired.
The only problem is that the link (HTML) does not display .. I get the compiled code, displayed in the page.

```
           var html = "<a href='#' ng-click='GotoDoc(" + link + ")'>" + linkText + "</a>"

            link = $compile(html)($scope);
```

{{link}}   shows up like 'ms-appx//acad//www/index.htm#'

instead of a normal hyperlink.

What am I doing wrong? 
   Is it being compiled properly?

If I don't compile it displays fine.. but the ng-click is dead.

Comment: Please post your value of link/linkText or html after it has been created

Comment: So wehre does `linktext` come from?... a small snippet showing undefined variables is hard to troubleshoot...should be posting all relevant code

Comment: try   link = 'http://www.cnn.com'        and GotoDoc      $scope.GotoDoc = function(url) { window open(url)}